# How to Filter Emails in Gmail with two TO: addresses

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I encountered following problem:

I send three kinds of emails:

- first that has in TO: only my employee email address: *@mycompany.com
- second that has in TO: my employee and my client address: *@mycompany.com and myclient@someothercompany.com
- third that has in TO: only my client email address: myclient@someothercompany.com

I want to build a filter which will assign a label to all emails which were sent to my clients or to my client and my employee but I want to avoid those that were sent *only* to my employee.

In other words I want to label all emails, but not those which were sent only between me and my employees.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -3):

there is no way . we can use combine filters in from field only but not in TO field